# Error de re direccionamiento en PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Lo que pasa es que intento redireccionar a otra página pero me sale este error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

La línea que lo genera me indica que es ésta:

```
 header("location: " . URL . "Home/newProcess");
```

puse las funciones de `ob_start()` para envíar las cabeceras en cualquier parte del documento, pero sigue apareciendo.

Answer (score 0):

Estás haciendo un output (imprimiendo en pantalla el html, cualquier salida) antes de esta instrucción.

Tienes que hacer las validaciones que hacen estas redirecciones antes de cualquier salida HTML.

Comment: eso hago, tenía una línea que es la que me imprime el mensaje en la vista donde se carga esa alerta, pero leyendo me dicen que primero se envía la cabecera y luego se carga la información, así es la función completa

Comment: // header("location: " . URL . "Home/newProcess");

 // $_SESSION["mensaje"] = "<script>toastr.success('Se registró el proceso')</script>";

Comment: @EstebanCalle Por favor, cualquier código adicional, ponlo editando la pregunta. En los comentarios es difícil de leer. :)